# Text goes out of the Textview after TextSize has changed

Tags: android, text, textview, text-size

The problem is, if i make a text in a textview bigger then size of the view, the text moves down. If i now make the text smaller while the programm is runnung, the text moves more down. and i see no possibility to put the text in the start position without restarting the app.

Perhaps someone knows about the problem and can give me a hint, what i can do.

the xml of the TextView is:

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rahmen"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

And I change the size of this TextView with a button:

```
TextView.setTextSize(10);
TextView.setTextSize(200);
TextView.setTextSize(10);
```

After this the text is under the TextView margins and so not visible anymore.

thx

sorry i wanted to post some photos to show my problem but i am not allowed until i have a better reputation...

Comment: Is the layout height and width set as wrap content for your textview ??

Comment: yes it is wrap content because i have many more textviews in this layout.

Comment: but thats not the problem. i think the size of the text in the text view gets bigger then the textview as itself. and it seems that the text always is displayed at the bottom of this area. And if i make the text smaller again the size of this area is still bigger then the textview...

Comment: can you post your code snippet and the xml ?

Comment: You don't have to use the maxHeight, maxWidth

Comment: Before i had a fixed height and width. But i sill had the same problem. And the size of the TextView must be this size and may not change...

Answer (score 0):

this is the only thing I am doing and it looks like its working okay for me.

Here's the code..

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/change_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Change Text"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/change_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Default Text"/>
```

and here's the code to change the text:

```
defaulttext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.change_text_view);
        changeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.change_button);

        changeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                defaulttext.setTextSize(80);

            }
        });
```

Even after doing this, there's no effect on the position of the textview. I am not sure what exactly is the issue in your code.

### Here's the edited answer:

Before text change:

[image: Test Image]

After text change:

[image: Test image 2]

Now, this is happening because I am using the nine patch as background and that allows your textview to shape in whatever manner you want it to be.

Here's a link to the nine patch I am using:

http://imageshack.com/a/img41/6466/iy33.png

See if this helps you with the problem.

Comment: If you can, go to https://imageshack.com/ and put your image there and you can get the link for it. and then just put the link in this comment.

Comment: is would love to show you my pictures... i had already two buttons to make the bigger in 10 units and with the other make it smaller again...this works until the text is in the textview margins. if the text is bigger the lower part of the text is not visible anymore. and when i make the text smaller the text moves down...

Comment: I am sorry but this sounds a bit funny ..Anyways, Can you post your code where you are doing all that ? apart from the code mentioned above.

Comment: I see your problem now..lemme get back to you in 5mins

Comment: I see that you are just using normal image for your background and not the nine patch image

Comment: thats why i have a fixed size in the textview. but whats the problem with that?

Comment: if the text changes its size to more than the size of the image background you are using, then the text parts will be not visible because its going out of the image's resolution. Now, if you set the text to a smaller size than the image background's resolution, your textview will work fine.

Comment: yes but you can see in my second image that the text still is outside when it has a smaller size again...and thats my main problem...and i have no idea how i can put it back in the image view...

Comment: Agree..but you know .. I will have to look at your code at least to figure out the exact issue. If you can do that, I will be happy to help.

Comment: i can show you all my code but i dont think it will help in this situation...how can i send you my xml and src file?

Comment: That will be great. Can you zip it and upload it in google drive and send me the link for that ?

Comment: Yes.. trying to see where exactly is the problem .. mann.. what r u doing in the layout!!

Comment: hmm dont find any answer? ;)